# OAuth2 Implicit Grant wihtout resource owner authorisation

Tags: security, asp.net-web-api, oauth, owin

This is something driving me crazy since last 48 hours.

The idea is to have implicit grant for SPA application with auth server (managed by us). I can see the flow where user have to login using our own identity database or via google (for e.g.) which is fine.

but there are other scenarios where Auth server only want to make sure the request have come from a valid (registered client). For e.g. in the Application (Resource)'s new User Registration function or Forget password function. Obviously under this scenario User will not be logged in as he/she does not have username/password in first place.

Under this circumstances how do we use implicit grant just to make sure the request is coming from a valid client and not some hacker's site?

Is this even possible through implicit grant?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With implicit flow the client should be registered with a client ID and callback URL.